# How to reshape column to matrix using dynamic array function in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have an excel sheet with some column data that I would like to use for some matrix multiplications using MMULT-function. For that purpose I need to reshape the column data first. I would like to do the reshaping using a dynamic array function since that could then feed directly into the MMULT function without having to actually display the reshaped matrix in the sheet (i.e. keeping only the column with the input data visible for the user). I am aware of ideas such as the one outlined here http://www.cpearson.com/excel/VectorToMatrix.aspx however however as far as I can see that requires having the reshaped data displayed in the sheet which I do not want. An alternative could be to enter the arrays directly in the formula using curly brackets, however as far as I can see this notation does not allow cell-references, i.e. something like MMULT({A1,A2,A3;A4,A5,A6},{A7,A8;A9,A10;A11,A12}) is not allowed. Any ideas for solving this issue?

An example is shown below, basically I have the column-data in my sheet, but do not want to repeat the data (as reshaped data), however, I would still like to be able to do display the square of the reshaped matrix.

Reshaped data and matrix multiplication:
[image]

Comment: You haven't given details of the reshaping you require. A small example dataset with expected result would help greatly.

Comment: Have a look at [`WRAPCOLS()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wrapcols-function-d038b05a-57b7-4ee0-be94-ded0792511e2). And possibly `BYROW()` to replace tedious `MMULT()`, however I still don't see what the expected end-result should be.

Comment: Hi Jos, I have shown an example above, basically what I want to avoid is displaying the reshaped data in the sheet, but using the reshaped matrix as input for the MMULT function. I.e. something like MMULT({B3,B4,B5;B6,B7,B8;B9,B10,B11},{B3,B4,B5;B6,B7,B8;B9,B10,B11}) to calculate the square of the reshaped matrix.

Comment: Hi JvDV, WRAPCOLS seems to be exactly what I am looking for, unfortunately I do not have this function available, My excel version is "Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14326.21008) 64-bit ".

Comment: Then please can you let us know what the final expected result is for your sample data. The altered array dimensions are just an intermediate step. Edit the body of the question to showcase what it is you are trying.

Comment: So you're currently asking for a 9-row-by-1-column array to be reshaped into a 3-row-by-3-column array. But can you give a more generalised version of your requirement? What if the original array were 10 rows? Or 15 rows?

Comment: Hi Jos, for my purpose it does not need to be general, it is always 9x1 column vector that should be reshaped to a 3x3 matrix. But in general you could say that I need a dynamic array function that turns a Nx1 column vector into a MxP matrix where M*P=N.

Comment: So just `INDEX(B3:B11,SEQUENCE(ROWS(B3:B11)/3,3))`

Comment: @JvdV That's just matrix multiplication: 30=(1x1)+(2x4)+(3x7), i.e. first row by first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reshaping a `9x1` array into a `3x3` array:

`INDEX(B3:B11,SEQUENCE(ROWS(B3:B11)/3,3))`